# Adding attachment to Outlook email with VSTO

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, outlook-2013

I'm trying to develop a custom attach file button that will show on the ribbon of a new, blank email. ( I would like to insert the button in the highlighted section)

[image]
[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268870.aspx) from MSDN shows how to attach a file and create the email, which is useful but not exactly what I'm after. Is there any documentation on adding attachments to emails which are already open?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Attachments.Add
```

Comment: ActiveInspector is a method which is not valid in given context? I can do Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;  but there is no Attachments property?

Comment: CurrentItem returns a generic object, you need to cast it appropriately. You can read the Class property using reflection and if it is 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail) cast to MailItem. Or simply cast using the "as" operator and check if the result is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the OfficeRibbon context so I ended up using the following code:

```
var item = this.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
var mailItem = item.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment.Location, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, attachment.FileName);
```